# How can I reverse an audio file?

Tags: java, audio

I want to know how I can take an audio file and instead of playing it forwards I want to play it backward.

This is what I have so far

```
    public void addSong(String song) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException {

    AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(song + ".wav"));

    System.out.println(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(song + ".wav")));

    AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
    Clip clip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

    songs.add(song);
    songsMedia.add(audioStream);
    clips.add(clip);
    //display.makeButton(song);
}
public void playSong(String song) throws LineUnavailableException, IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    if(songs.contains(song)){
        int nFrames = songsMedia.get(0).getFormat().getFrameSize();

        stopSong=true;
        index = songs.indexOf(song);


        clips.get(index).open(songsMedia.get(index));
        clips.get(index).start();
        playingSongs.add(clips.get(index));



    }else if(song == "Pause/Play"){
        System.out.print("");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(song);
        System.out.println("Cannot Find Song");
    }
}
```

How can I take all of the samples from the audio stream so that I can re-arrange them?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `Clip` API doesn't expose the data held by the `Clip`. But you can get what you want by using `SourceDataLine` for playback instead, and adding a few steps.

First, get all the individual samples by using an `AudioInputStream`.

The individual bytes need to be processed in small chunks according the frame size as specified in the audio format, and ordered in reverse "frame" order. For example, if the audio format requires four bytes per frame (as with stereo, 16-bit encoding), then the reversal will happen in chunks of four bytes.

For example, a 4-frame long audio file comprised of the bytes 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15, in reverse frame order becomes 12,13,14,15,8,9,10,11,4,5,6,7,0,1,2,3.

The byte data can be played via a `SourceDataLine`. I think you should be able to find code examples of `SourceDataLine` playback. The key change you will have to make is to get the data for playback from the reverse-ordered array rather than from `AudioInputStream` as is normally done.

The github library *AudioCue* was built around the idea of making a sort of super Clip, where the individual PCM data frames are accessible. You could inspect the method [loadURL](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue/blob/master/src/main/java/com/adonax/audiocue/AudioCue.java) at line 359 as an example of loading data into an array via `AudioInputStream`. That example converts the data to PCM floats instead of leaving it as bytes. So you'd have to make some changes/simplifications. Storing as floats makes it easier to do things like mixing, and 'variable speed' playback, which might be useful if you decide you also want to speed up or slow down, forward or back.